# How does StringField in WTForms Create Fields in HTML File

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I'm a beginner in coding and currently learning Python. I have been using Flask and WTForms recently to create a registration form. Besides just following tutorials to build the form, I'm also trying to understand it a little bit and see how it works (just generally). So my question is about the StringField.

I have created an html file called registr.html and it will be rendered. Inside of this html file, there is two lines of code that will create a field for the user to input their username, see below:

> {{ form.username.label }}
>
> {{ form.username }}

And in my Python application, I have created something below, say Section A:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

And below, say Section B:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

Here is my question. I understand *form.username.label* will put the label "Username" above the input field so people know this is where they input their username. And then I think what *form.username* does is actually creating a field so people can enter something in there. So my understanding is that *username* is an attribute that is equal to *StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])*, which is an object of class *StringField*, and since *form* is equal to *RegistrationForm()*, So executing *form.username* in the html file is like executing *Registration.StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])*. Am I correct, here? If so, how executing an object *StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])* can create an input field in the html? Can we execute an object? I think we can only execute a method in a class, correct? So there must be something else going on that I don't understand. Again I'm still a beginner and learning Python. So any help is be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a default render widget. You can overwrite the widget if you need custom HTML to be rendered (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html). The specific the render widget used is here:

```
class Input(object):
    """
    Render a basic ``<input>`` field.
    This is used as the basis for most of the other input fields.
    By default, the `_value()` method will be called upon the associated field
    to provide the ``value=`` HTML attribute.
    """

    html_params = staticmethod(html_params)

    def __init__(self, input_type=None):
        if input_type is not None:
            self.input_type = input_type

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("id", field.id)
        kwargs.setdefault("type", self.input_type)
        if "value" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["value"] = field._value()
        if "required" not in kwargs and "required" in getattr(field, "flags", []):
            kwargs["required"] = True
        return Markup("<input %s>" % self.html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs))
```